# カレントディレクトリの扱いについて

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
以下の事象について質問します。

任意のフォルダに「PAUSE」一行のみのBATファイルを作成し、
それをEmEditorで開き、メニューの「関連付けられたプログラム」で実行すると、
カレントディレクトリがEmEditorのインストールされたディレクトリで
コマンドプロンプトが起動してしまいます。
※この事象は.jsファイルや.vbsファイルでも同様のようです。

上記は正常な挙動でしょうか。
私としては、BATファイルが保存されてあるフォルダを
カレントディレクトリとして起動して欲しいのですが、
設定変更などで対応可能でしょうか。

Comment: [外部ツールの設定の]から[関連付けられたプログラム]の[プロパティ]の[初期ディレクトリ]を `$(Dir)` にしてみてください。

Comment: @user40304 そのコメントがこの質問への回答になっている場合、ぜひ回答を投稿してみることをご検討ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ツール] メニュー -> [外部ツール] -> [外部ツールの設定] で <外部ツールダイアログ> を開いて
[関連付けられたプログラム] -> [プロパティ] で <外部ツールのプロパティ> を開いて
[初期ディレクトリ] に `$(Dir)` を設定てみてください。
(他にもツールバーのアイコンを右クリックでも <外部ツールのプロパティ> を呼び出せます)

余談ですが
BATファイルで自身のあるドライブとディレクトリは容易に取得できるので `"%~d0%~p0"`
個人的には BATファイルの１行目に
`@Echo off & chcp 65001>nul & cd /d "%~d0%~p0"`
としてコードページの設定等と一緒にカレントディレクトリの設定をしてます。
これで他のアプリケーションから呼び出しても問題なくなります。

※コメントに思いつき書きましたが、検証して回答とし書き直しました。